# Is it possible to ignore word break characters with word-wrap: break-word?

Tags: css

I'd like to have `word-wrap:break-word` ignore all word break characters, such as a hyphen, so that all the text is wrapped. Is that possible?

If you look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9qEqBINWOMTNWsBMo78g?p=preview) you can see that the second paragraph breaks at the hyphen.

Markup

```
  <body>
    <p>IfcDoor_M_ToiletPartition:0915x1525mm:0915x1525mm:229928_27dLDsxMX8Sv5rKurGZzuM</p>
    <p>IfcDoor_M_ToiletPartition:0915x-1525mm:0915x1525mm:229928_27dLDsxMX8Sv5rKurGZzuM</p>
  </body>
```

CSS

```
p {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `word-break: break-all;`

Amended your plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/5YfqCeBNAcLEIDz6lGD7?p=preview).